# How to tell node-gyp / node-sass that I already have my node-headers?

Tags: node.js, node-gyp, node-sass

I'm currently working behind a proxy that doesn't allow me the HTTP GET request stage of this command:

`node node-sass/scripts/build.js`

Request stage:

```
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.8.0/node-v10.8.0-headers.tar.gz
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
```

As said, I downloaded those headers (and particularly the mentioned-in-the-log tarball) locally. How do I tell node-sass that I do have my file locally? I tried looking in `build.js` directly, but I couldn't manage to do what I want ; that might be out of my level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so I managed to do it. I simply had to unpack the tarball, and make point a `nodedir` config in my .yarnrc to the folder created by unpacking.
So:

```
tar -xzvf your_headers_package
yarn config set nodedir your_headers_folder
```

And that worked for me. I feel... pretty dumb now.

Answer (score 2):

For those trying to set up node-gyp with no internet access:

- **Get the node headers file:** `curl -O https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.3/node-v14.17.3-headers.tar.gz` *(make sure you have the correct node version appropriate, and you need a machine with internet)*
- **Copy header tarball to offline machine** (approach may vary depending on your situation an example may be to winscp to vm)
- **Create the node-gyp folder that the library looks for if it's not already existing**: `mkdir -p ~/.cache/node-gyp/14.17.3` (PITFALL: in some versions node-gyp folder is under `~/.node-gyp`)
- **tar the file to node-gyp folder**: `tar -xf node-v14.17.3-headers.tar.gz --directory ~/.cache/.node-gyp/6.10.1/ --strip-components 1` *(make sure you have the correct versions here)*
- **create the `installVersion` manually**: `echo 9 >~/.node-gyp/6.10.1/installVersion` *(usually it is created automatically if you have internet access)*

Comment: hi can check if the node-gyp folder is node-gyp or .node-gyp?